# Find closest match for values in one column, if additional columns match 100%

Tags: r, data.table, matching, closest

I have two data frames of unequal lengths. I would like to add value2 from df2 to df1 where the difference between value1a and value1b is minimal. Not all rows in df1 will receive a match from df 2 because df2 is shorter. st, year and doy must match between df1 and df2 before the closest match is found (value1a and value1b) as the dataset comprises multiple samplings over several years at the same stations.

```
st <- c("ST1", "ST2", "ST2", "ST2", "ST3")
year <- c(2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2013)
doy <- c(20,29,4,4,20)

value1a <- c(200, 250, 240, 250, 260)
value1b <- c(201, 258, 240, 251, 180)
value2 <- c(5,6,7,8.5,10)

df1 <- data.frame(st, year, doy, value1a)
df2 <- data.frame(st, year, doy, value1b, value2); df2 <- df2[1:4,]
```

I shortened df2 to keep the same column names but show that it may have not the same number of rows and information as df1.
Ideally, the output would be something like this:

```
     st year    doy value1a value1b value2
1   ST1 2011    20  200      201    5.0
2   ST2 2011    29  250      258    6.0
3   ST2 2012    4   240      240    7.0
4   ST2 2012    4   250      251    8.5
5   ST3 2013    20  260      NA     NA
```

I have looked into the closest.match() and related functions, but have not been able to get it working when prior matches in other columns must be succesful. Any ideas?

*Edit: I changed the dataframes according to the suggestions below and hope it clarifies the problem. I  apologize to everyone who already put in the effort to answer!

For practical illustration in case oceanographers are around: I am working with water column data. At the same station on the same day of a year, certain data are obtained during the first sampling according to value1a over depth in the water. Then this is repeated on the same day of a year only very slightly later (hence year and doy match), but automatically recorded value1b is slightly different. I would like to match value2 obtained only on the second sampling with the data obtained on the first sampling.

Comment: Because you said *"difference ... is minimal"*, I'm going to guess that there should be logic in the merge/join that compares those two variables. Because of this, I suggest you provide a `df2` that includes multiple matches on one or more sets of keys, requiring follow-on minimization.

Comment: You are right, the example data was not showing the real problem. I will try to provide more appropriate data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attempting to key off of your *"difference between value1a and value1b is minimal"* statement, this is a two-step operation: merge/join, then reduce based on the difference.

Because the current sample data doesn't test this requirement, I'll duplicate one of the rows with slightly different values to show that the minimal is being chosen.

```r
df2 <- rbind(df2, transform(df2[2,], value1b = 300, value2 = 6.1))
df2
#     st year doy2 value1b value2
# 1  ST1 2011   21     201    5.0
# 2  ST2 2011   29     258    6.0
# 3  ST2 2012    4     240    7.0
# 4  ST2 2013   20     180    8.5
# 21 ST2 2011   29     300    6.1
```

Also, because I am not certain that the `df1` rows are perfectly unique with respect to `st`, `year`, and `doy`, I'll add an `rn` (row number) field in each step so that I can be certain to reduce correctly. (That is, if I don't do this and those three fields are not unique, then I will over-reduce your data.)

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  left_join(., df2, by = c("st", "year", doy = "doy2")) %>%
  arrange(abs(value1a - value1b)) %>%
  group_by(rn) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 4 x 7
#   st     year   doy value1a    rn value1b value2
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <int>   <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 ST1    2011    20     200     1      NA   NA  
# 2 ST2    2011    29     250     2     258    6  
# 3 ST2    2012     4     240     3     240    7  
# 4 ST2    2013    20     260     4     180    8.5
```

### data.table

Some notes:

- I'm using `magrittr`'s pipe (`%>%`) purely for demonstration, as I think it breaks things out visually very well; it is not required
- the way `data.table` merges things, the `doy` field retains the name of the *right* table (`df2`), so I rename it with `data.table::setnames`
- a small feature/bug in `data.table` prevents first-time printing of a result when the last `[`-operation is an assignment with `:=`; this is [FAQ 2.23](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#why-do-i-have-to-type-dt-sometimes-twice-after-using-to-print-the-result-to-console), and is both aesthetic-only and not a factor if there's another operation; because of this, I added a seemingly empty `%>% .[]` to print it to the console here

```r
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
df1[, rn := .I] %>%
  df2[., on = .(st, year, doy2 = doy)] %>%
  .[ order(abs(value1a - value1b)), ] %>%
  .[, .SD[1,], by = .(rn) ] %>%
  .[, rn := NULL] %>%
  setnames(., old = "doy2", new = "doy") %>%
  .[]
#     st year doy value1b value2 value1a
# 1: ST2 2012   4     240    7.0     240
# 2: ST2 2011  29     258    6.0     250
# 3: ST2 2013  20     180    8.5     260
# 4: ST1 2011  20      NA     NA     200
```

(There are ways to tell `data.table` what to do when `mult`iple matches are found. I did not test to see if order can be assured, but if there's a way to know that with certainty, then perhaps this can be simplified a little.)

### SQL-like

(Using the original, not-`data.table` versions of `df1` and `df2`.)

This creates a couple of row-number counters, similar to `rn` in the `data.table` solution, for similar reasons.

```r
sqldf::sqldf("
  with t1 as (
    select df1.*, row_number() over () as rn1
    from df1
  ),
  t12 as (
    select t1.*, t2.value2,
      row_number() over (partition by t1.rn1) as rn2
    from t1
      left join df2 t2 on t1.st=t2.st and t1.year=t2.year and t1.doy=t2.doy2
    order by abs(value1a - value1b)
  )
  select st, year, doy, value1a, value2 from t12 where rn2 = 1")
#    st year doy value1a value2
# 1 ST1 2011  20     200     NA
# 2 ST2 2012   4     240    7.0
# 3 ST2 2011  29     250    6.0
# 4 ST2 2013  20     260    8.5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Once I figured out what it does (and that in my original data, value1a and value1b actually have the same column name, renamed to value.x and value.y after the join), it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R solution:

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = c("st", "year", "doy"), by.y = c("st", "year", "doy2"), all = TRUE)
```

You can also use `dplyr`:

```
df3 <- full_join(df1,df2,by = c("st" = "st", "year" = "year", "doy" = "doy2"))
```

This gives you:

```
   st year doy value1a value1b value2
1 ST1 2011  20     200      NA     NA
2 ST1 2011  21      NA     201    5.0
3 ST2 2011  29     250     258    6.0
4 ST2 2012   4     240     240    7.0
5 ST2 2013  20     260     180    8.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a long alternative from `dplyr` package.

```
  library(dplyr)
    df3 <- data.frame(df1, df2)
    df3 %>% 
      mutate(value1a = ifelse(year == year.1 & st == st.1 & doy == doy2, value1a, NA),
             value1b = ifelse(year == year.1 & st == st.1 & doy == doy2, value1b, NA),
             value2 = ifelse(year == year.1 & st == st.1 & doy == doy2, value2, NA)) %>% 
      select(st, year, doy, value1a, value1b, value2)

#   st year doy value1a value1b value2
#1 ST1 2011  20      NA      NA     NA
#2 ST2 2011  29     250     258      6
#3 ST2 2012   4     240     240      7
#4 ST2 2013  20     260     180    8.5
```

Comment: (1) Don't use a literal string of `"NA"` if you intend to indicate something ... first, you're changing all data from numbers to strings; second, if you mean "no match found", use `NA`, not `"NA"`. (2) This method only works when all rows are already perfectly aligned, a bad idea. (3) The requested operation is a merge/join, this answer is not that.

Answer (score 0):

So I used dplyr with the left_join() argument which doesn't, in itself get the right answer. I then grouped the rows using group_by(). After grouping them you can filter out the values that aren't close to each other by comparing the absolute values of the different values for value1a and value1b subtracted from each other. You have include an additional logical statement in filter() so it doesn't automatically remove rows with NAs when evaluating the other NA statement. SO it looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df3 <- left_join(df1, df2, by = c("st", "year", "doy"))
df3 %>% group_by(st, year, doy, value1a) %>%
  filter(is.na(value1b) | abs(value1a - value1b) == 
           min(abs(value1a - value1b)))
```

The results I got looked like:

```
st     year   doy value1a value1b value2
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 ST1    2011    20     200     201    5  
2 ST2    2011    29     250     258    6  
3 ST2    2012     4     240     240    7  
4 ST2    2012     4     250     251    8.5
5 ST3    2013    20     260      NA   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using rolling join in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
df2[df1, on=.(st, year, doy, value1b=value1a), roll="nearest",
    c(.(value1a=value1a), mget(names(df2)))]
```

output:

```
   value1a  st year doy value1b value2
1:     200 ST1 2011  20     200    5.0
2:     250 ST2 2011  29     250    6.0
3:     240 ST2 2012   4     240    7.0
4:     250 ST2 2012   4     250    8.5
5:     260 ST3 2013  20     260     NA
```