# merge in data.table on ID and closest date in R

Tags: r, data.table

I want to merge two data frames in `data.table` by the same ID. The first data frame df1 has unique IDs, the second df2 has duplicated IDs. I only want to merge IDs from df2 with the closest date to df1. Every other ID in df2 should be dropped. I was trying the `nearestTimeandID` function in `bayesbio`, but it takes too much time.
I tried to follow another comment suggesting the roll="nearest" in `data.table` but the IDs are still duplicated.

This is the function I used in nearestTimeandDate:

```
library(data.table)

together <- nearestTimeandID(df1, df2, timeCol1 = "Date1", timeCol2 = "Date2", IDcol = "ID")
```

and with the `roll = "nearest"`:

```
setDT(df1)[, join_date := Date1] 
setDT(df2)[, join_date := Date2] 
together <- df1[df2, on = .(ID, join_date), roll = "nearest"]
```

How can I merge the datasets and drop the duplicated IDs that are not the closest date in a time efficient way? Thanks!

---

sample data:

```
d <- as.Date("2020-07-10")
df1 <- data.table(ID=1, Date1=d, Val1=11)
df2 <- data.table(ID=rep(1, 2), Date2=c(d-3, d+1), Val2=21:22)
```

Comment: Earlier I answered a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63194230/3358272. Otherwise, questions on SO do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically after `set.seed(1)`), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: try something like `df2[, rn := .I]; df2[unique(df2[df1, on=.(ID, Date2=Date1), roll="nearest", rn])]`. If there are 2 dates are equally close, what would you do with them?

Comment: I always want that 'Date1>Date2'.

Answer (score 0):

This is a `tidyverse` answer but perhaps you can apply the same logic to `data.table`. The key is to only find the closest datetime once you've already joined. First, the two datasets, where `df1` has 10 unique `id`s but `df2` is 100,000 rows long with repeats. The datetimes are randomly sampled within a 200-day period:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(
  id = 1:10,
  datetime = Sys.time() + runif(10, -60*60*24*100, 60*60*24*100)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  id = sample(1:10, 100000, replace = TRUE),
  datetime = Sys.time() + runif(100000, -60*60*24*100, 60*60*24*100)
)
```

Now we join on `id` but then also `group_by` it in the resulting dataframe, and then `filter` for rows with the minimal distance between the two datetime columns:

```
df1 %>%
  inner_join(df2, by = 'id', suffix = c('.1', '.2')) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(abs(datetime.1 - datetime.2) == min(abs(datetime.1 - datetime.2)))

# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   id [10]
      id datetime.1          datetime.2         
   <int> <dttm>              <dttm>             
 1     1 2020-07-28 15:10:56 2020-07-28 15:18:37
 2     2 2020-10-26 03:33:34 2020-10-26 03:34:02
 3     3 2020-09-03 08:50:15 2020-09-03 08:52:15
 4     4 2020-08-01 07:33:25 2020-08-01 06:55:01
 5     5 2020-08-24 15:09:55 2020-08-24 15:07:50
 6     6 2020-09-18 02:16:17 2020-09-18 02:25:16
 7     7 2020-10-19 11:31:33 2020-10-19 12:28:08
 8     8 2020-10-06 07:42:08 2020-10-06 07:42:41
 9     9 2020-10-21 14:20:12 2020-10-21 14:28:04
10    10 2020-04-24 17:17:59 2020-04-24 17:08:51
```